# How can I make ensure caffe using GPU?

Tags: python-2.7, gpu, caffe, pycaffe

Is there any way to ensure caffe using GPU? I was compiled caffe after installing CUDA driver and without `CPU_ONLY` flag in cmake and while compiling cmake logged detection of CUDA 8.0.

But while train a sample, I doubt it using GPU according `nvidia-smi` result. How can I ensure?

Comment: if you don't see caffe running in `nvidia-smi` it probably not using GPU. have you set `solver_mode: gpu` in your solver.prototxt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surest way I know is to properly configure the solver.prototxt file.
Include the line

solver_mode: GPU

If you have any specifications for the engine to use in each layer of your model, you'll want to also make sure they refer to GPU software.

Answer (score 4):

For future caffe wanderers scouring around, this finally did the trick for me:

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
caffe.set_device(0)
```

I did have `solver_mode: GPU`, and it would show the process on the gpu, but the 'GPU Memory Usage' as seen using `nvidia-smi` was not enough to fit my model (so I knew something was wrong...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::GPU);` in you program explicitly.

To make sure the process is using GPU, you can use `nvidia-smi` command in ubuntu to which process use GPU.

As to me, I use MTCNN to do face detection(implement by caffe):

I use `nvidia-smi` command to show processes who use GPU, if you want to see it by interval use `watch nvidia-smi`.

As below image, we can see that the process `mtcnn_c(use caffe backend)` is using GPU.

[image]